# How the view are refereed under MainActivity In android

Tags: android, xml, oop

Here is the XML code for a simple TextView:

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:id="@+id/test"/>
```

Then, in MainActivity, it is used like this:

```
TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
test.setText("test");
```

I want to know how the view is accessed in Main class, which is defined in xml layout.

Can anyone explain how it happens?

Comment: Can you explain more your question? It's not very clear what you want to know.

Comment: We creating views in XML layout ,How we using those views inside MainClass TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
how does this code works

Comment: take a look in my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

> how the view accessed in Main class

To be honest, i dont know the process in detail. Let me help you on what i know :

1. The `Activity` will search the layout XML in `setContentView` method.
2. After the layout has been found, we can use `findViewById` to link the instance (test - in your case) we created to the layout XML.
3. If the ID is found, the instance (Java) and XML will be linked.

Of course, you can do something like :

```
TextView test2 = new TextView(this);
```

Which means the instance is **not** must exist in XML.

Sorry English is not my native language.

Answer (score 1):

On your Activity, you have:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    //...
}
```

According to Android documentation, [setContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)) is responsible for linking your XML layout to your Activity:

> Set the activity content to an explicit view. This view is placed
>   directly into the activity's view hierarchy. It can itself be a
>   complex view hierarchy.

After the Activity's content view is set, you can use [findViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) in order to access the views of the XML linked to your Activity:

> Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that
>   was processed in onCreate(Bundle).

Hope it helps you to understand this process! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the method

1.when you create or declare a text view or something like that a reference is generated in your R file(JAVA file).

2.which is what you access through

`R.id.test`

this is how your linking works